# C++ handling unanticipated errors

Tags: c++, arrays, exception

I need to learn C++ basics for a research project, and I'm experimenting with error/exception handling. I did use the `throw` command successfully to anticipate on events that might occur (like divide by zero), but I cannot figure out how to catch unanticipated exceptions. Take this example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

void arrayOutOfBound()
{
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    try
    {
        cout << "This should not display: " << a[5] << endl;
    }
    catch(runtime_error &e)
    /* catch(exception &e)     // also does not work  */
    {
        cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    arrayOutOfBound();
}
```

I guess I have to use `throw` statements somewhere, but suppose I really did not know that `a[5]` wouldn't work (or the user entered this index and I did not check for the array size), then how can I prevent the program from crashing? (as this happens in the Visual C++ Express 2010 debugger)

Note: if I would do `try { int result = a[5]; }` first, outside the block, and try to use `cout << result` at the end, the program does not compile. The compiler is trying to help me, but therefore I cannot try the exception handling.

Comment: The point isn't really knowing whether or not `a[5]` will succeed, but being prepared (in the same way) for `a[x]` to fail. If you aren't prepared, your program ends because it's not handling it for you. That of course assumes you have an array class capable of checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> suppose I really did not know that a[5] wouldn't work (or the user entered this index and I did not check for the array size), then how can I prevent the program from crashing?

You simply can't. An out of bounds access to an array causes undefined behavior in C++, it won't throw an exception. When you are lucky enough, you get a crash.

Comment: Ah, okay. That sounds hopeful! ;-)

Comment: Interesting that you say "it won't throw an exception" yet felt the need to be extremely pedantic in response to my comment which said "that will never throw an exception".

Comment: @Ed S.: I agree, it certainly is interesting!

Comment: ...I liked that comment, +1 :D

Answer (score 2):

Sorry can't resist quoting an obvious meme "native arrays... that's not how you do it!" :D

the code you've written above uses a native array which is in essence a memory location. so by saying a[5] you're saying i want to use the 4 bytes at address (a +  4 * sizeof(int)) to be interpreted as an int. This won't throw an exception. it is undefined behavior and might return garbage. if you use -O2 or some such compiler flag, it MAY return 0 and btw, this is a grade A source of buffer overrun :D

Here's a template class that'll solve your problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T, size_t COUNT>
class CheckedArray
{
public:
    class OutOfBounds : public std::exception
    {
        public:
            virtual const char* what() const throw(){ return "Index is out of bounds"; }    
    };
    CheckedArray(){}
    virtual ~CheckedArray(){}
    const T& operator[] (size_t index) const
    {
        if(index >= COUNT){ throw OutOfBounds(); }
        return m_array[index];
    }
    T& operator[] (size_t index)    
    {
        if(index >= COUNT){ throw OutOfBounds(); }
        return m_array[index];
    }
private:
    T m_array[COUNT];
};
void arrayOutOfBound()
{
    //int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    CheckedArray<int,3> a;
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[2] = 3;
    try
    {
        cout << "This should not display: " << a[5] << endl;
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)     // this will kick in
    {
        cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    arrayOutOfBound();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this behavior, recommend you write a class e.g. "CheckedArray" which wraps an array and performs bounds checking. If you do this in full generality, it will be a template class and you will need to know about overloading operator[] of course.

Alternatively, if you're happy with the overhead of a dynamically allocated array, use `std::vector`, in particular its `at` member function throws an exception on out-of-range index. As a side benefit, your array can now be (re)sized at run-time.

Even better, use `std::array` which also has the throwing `at` function (but is not resizable.)

Comment: Or use something like `std::array`, which is already all there.

Comment: I understood from Deitel's book that vectors are indeed better than the array I am using. The example was just for error handling. First try to do with a divideByZero() but the compiler managed to do fine. Unfortunately, in this case ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could have caught the array bound error had you used `std::array`, instead of C style array, and the `.at()` member function

```
std::array <int, 5> stdArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

//array boundary check

 try  {
        cout << "trying to access out of bound element " << endl;
        cout << stdArray.at(5) << endl;
 } catch(std::exception &e) {
        cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
  }
```

Now the program does not crash, instead, you see this output
`Error: array::at: __n (which is 5) >= _Nm (which is 5)`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a handler for segmentation faults and such, you should check out signal.h

//John