# will Index Out Of Array Bounds throw exception or error before core in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

will Index Out Of Array Bounds throw exception or error when coring in C++?

I know if index out of array bound existed, there will exist one undefined actions for the code.
but what time it will core?

if the program will popup error/exception before it will core?

can I catch the exception or error be core?

Comment: There is no "coring" in C++.

Comment: You won't get any exceptions if you go out of bounds, just UB. Which does imply that a box saying "Out of bounds exception" could pop up.But it could just as likely post comments on StackOverflow =)

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can never be sure.

An out of bounds access to an array causes undefined behavior in C++, it won't throw an exception.

[C++ handling unanticipated errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711662/c-handling-unanticipated-errors)

Comment: 3ks, can you help this question？ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984778/when-core-crash-occur-if-there-one-error-exception-occurred

Comment: Technically, undefined behaviour could include throwing an exception ;)